# Numbers considered as constants

Tags: php, permissions

trying to create a folder on my Siteground hosting it gives me error:

> Warning: Use of undefined constant  0755 - assumed ' 0755' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)

So it considers my permission number as a inexistent constant. How to fix it? Is it a PHP configuration?

My code is very simple:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$invoices_folder_src = '/home/customer/www/xxxxxxx/yyyyyyy/dummyfolder';
        
if (!mkdir($invoices_folder_src, 0755, true))
    die('Failed to create directories...');
```

Thanks

Comment: This is a far stretch, but could it be that the space before `0755` isn't really a space? Or the zero is an `O`, although that is less likely. I notice that the space in front of the `0755` is include in the warning.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware it is correct! Maybe there is a hidden character.

Now the problem is another one. I arrived at this test because I have another folder creation problem in a more complex example, written in CakePHP, but I suppose I have to write another post for this.

Comment: It is correct indeed, I always use `mkdir(TMP, 0770, true);` without issues.

Comment: Yes, better to use another question for another problem.

Answer (score 1):

**Instead of this:** `if (!mkdir($invoices_folder_src, 0755, true))`

**Try this:** `if (!mkdir($invoices_folder_src, '0755', true))`

This way you pass the argument as a string rather than just a number.

Comment: If I look in the manual for [mkdir()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php), the syntax seems to be valid?

Comment: The function mkdir wants a int as second value, not a string.
In fact, inserting '0755', it gives me error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''0755'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ')' in ....